# Form won't submit after user checks a radio button and checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, forms, checkbox

I have a form with three radio buttons and a checkbox set up. A user must click one radio button and click the checkbox to submit. I am using [WP-Polls](https://github.com/lesterchan/wp-polls) which is a plugin for WordPress. For some reason, the form won't submit. I click a radio button, click the checkbox, but hitting submit does nothing. The live site can be seen [here](http://staging.keebs.com/). The relevant section is the dark voting section on top.

HTML

```
<form id="polls_form_1" class="wp-polls-form" action="/index.php" method="post">
    <p style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" id="poll_1_nonce" name="wp-polls-nonce" value="12a6404147"></p>
    <p style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="poll_id" value="1"></p>
    <div id="polls-1-ans">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" id="poll-answer-1" name="poll_1" value="1"></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="poll-answer-2" name="poll_1" value="2"></li>
        <li><input type="radio" id="poll-answer-3" name="poll_1" value="3"></li>
    </ul>

    <label class="check-terms"><input type="checkbox">I am over 18 and I have read and understand the Terms of Use</label>

    <input type="submit" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    window.poll_vote = function(num) {
        console.log(num);
    }

    $('.wp-polls-form').submit(function(e) {

        if (!$('input:radio', this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('Please pick a beat.');
            return false;
        }

        if (!$('input:checkbox', this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('Please agree to the Terms of Use.');
            return false;
        }

        poll_vote(1);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Here is the function for `poll_vote(1)`:

```
// When User Vote For Poll
function poll_vote(current_poll_id) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        if(!is_being_voted) {
            set_is_being_voted(true);
            poll_id = current_poll_id;
            poll_answer_id = '';
            poll_multiple_ans = 0;
            poll_multiple_ans_count = 0;
            if($('#poll_multiple_ans_' + poll_id).length) {
                poll_multiple_ans = parseInt($('#poll_multiple_ans_' + poll_id).val());
            }
            $('#polls_form_' + poll_id + ' input:checkbox, #polls_form_' + poll_id + ' input:radio, #polls_form_' + poll_id + ' option').each(function(i){
                if ($(this).is(':checked') || $(this).is(':selected')) {
                    if(poll_multiple_ans > 0) {
                        poll_answer_id = $(this).val() + ',' + poll_answer_id;
                        poll_multiple_ans_count++;
                    } else {
                        poll_answer_id = parseInt($(this).val());
                    }
                }
            });
            if(poll_multiple_ans > 0) {
                if(poll_multiple_ans_count > 0 && poll_multiple_ans_count <= poll_multiple_ans) {
                    poll_answer_id = poll_answer_id.substring(0, (poll_answer_id.length-1));
                    poll_process();
                } else if(poll_multiple_ans_count == 0) {
                    set_is_being_voted(false);
                    alert(pollsL10n.text_valid);
                } else {
                    set_is_being_voted(false);
                    alert(pollsL10n.text_multiple + ' ' + poll_multiple_ans);
                }
            } else {
                if(poll_answer_id > 0) {
                    poll_process();
                } else {
                    set_is_being_voted(false);
                    alert(pollsL10n.text_valid);
                }
            }
        } else {
            alert(pollsL10n.text_wait);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: When you say the form won't submit what do you mean?  Is there a javascript console error?  Is the pole_vote function getting called?

Comment: No, there's no error. I don't think the function is getting called.

Comment: have you tried closing the curly braces at the end of your poll_vote function, as I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @bryant I'm trying that now. The function came directly from the WP-Polls plugin so I'm not sure why it's missing. It was working fine before, but I modified it a bit to add the checkbox and it stopped working.

Comment: @bryant Sorry, that was my fault. I left it out. I just checked and the function has a closing bracket. I edited my post above.

Comment: I think your poll_vote function is getting called.  I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpbt8nha/)

Comment: @bryant Good call. Then, I really have no clue why it's not submitting.

Comment: it is not working because of the checkbox you added

Comment: will you be able to change the `poll_vote` method?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the new checkbox(terms & conditions) that is added inside the form.

If you can change the `poll_vote` function...

Change

```
<label class="check-terms"><input type="checkbox">
```

to

```
<label class="check-terms"><input type="checkbox" class="check-terms">
```

then

```
a("#polls_form_" + poll_id + " input:checkbox, #polls_form_" + poll_id + " input:radio, #polls_form_" + poll_id + " option")
```

to

```
a("#polls_form_" + poll_id + " input:checkbox, #polls_form_" + poll_id + " input:radio, #polls_form_" + poll_id + " option").not('.check-terms')
```

Comment: I changed these but the submit button still isn't submitting. I'm assuming you meant to type a `$` in front of the last two lines of code instead of an `a`, right?

Comment: I changed it to an `a` but it's still not submitting.

Comment: did you apply the changes in the site.. I can't see them

Comment: Yes, if you look through the dom, you'll see that `input` now has the class `check-terms` added to it. Also, I changed the function for `poll_vote()`located [here](https://github.com/lesterchan/wp-polls/blob/master/polls-js.dev.js), and overwrote the original file.

Comment: but you didn't add `.not('.check-terms')` in the `poll_vote` method

Comment: you will also have to remove `window.poll_vote = function(e) {
            console.log(e)
        }`

Comment: I added `.not('.check-terms')` inside that file that I linked to earlier. The file I linked is not my file, that's the original plugin file. I was just showing you which file I altered. Also, I just removed `window.poll_vote = function(e) { console.log(e) }' but that didn't work either. Now even though I click a radio button and check the checkbox, it says "Please choose a valid poll answer" and won't let me submit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61241/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-j82).

Comment: @J82 did you make any progress

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It ended up being the same result so I reverted all of the changes.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but at this point, I'm considering just hiring somebody to do it for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @J82 I can help you with that... if you can share a dev environment for remote support... if you wish